# CSS grid row not spanning as expected

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to span my second grid item over two rows.

I am able to achieve what I am looking for using the `grid-row: span 2` syntax. However I would like to achieve the same result using the `grid-row: x/y` syntax, where x and y are numeric values.

Problem is, the second syntax is producing unexpected results.
May someone please help me understand what it is I am doing wrong?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: rosybrown;
  background: #ffff;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.item {
  background: steelblue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: skyblue 1px solid;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  background-color: springgreen;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: royalblue;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  background: darkred;
}

.item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 1/4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"> item1 </div>
  <div class="item"> item2 </div>
  <div class="item"> item3 </div>
  <div class="item"> item4 </div>
  <div class="item"> item5 </div>
</div>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkkiq.png):

[image]

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bcirq.png):

[image]

I tried reading through the CSS to find the cause of the problem, and I also tried using different values.

Comment: I don't, unfortunately, have the opportunity to write an answer at the moment, but this seems to solve your problem: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f32567ep/), if anyone wants to take this as the basis of an answer then please do feel free; all I really did was add `grid-column: 3;` to the rules for `.item:nth-child(2)`.

Comment: The system seems  to be giving weight to the first setting of grid-row it finds. I don't have a full explanation of that, not knowing exactly what order it does its evaluation, but 'starting it off' by explicitly setting item1 to start in row 1 with a grid-row: 1 (no need to specify how many rows it spans) gives the result you want.

Comment: @David Thomas: Thank you for the help I really appreciate it.   That does solve my problem.                                                    
@A Harworth: Thank you for the help your solution also solves my problem.                                                                                                     I still do not understand why I am getting this behavior, most of the other examples work right off the bat without the need to explicitly define item positions.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

Add `grid-row: 1` to the first item, or `grid-column: 3` to the second item.

```css
.item:nth-child(1) {
   grid-column: 1/3;
   grid-row: 1; /* new */
 }
```

OR

```css
.item:nth-child(2) {
   grid-row: 1/3;
   grid-column: 3; /* new */
 }
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;  
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.item {
  background: steelblue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: skyblue 1px solid;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  background-color: springgreen;
  grid-row: 1; /* new */
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: royalblue;
  grid-row: 1/3;
  /* grid-column: 3; */ /* new */
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  background: darkred;
}

.item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: rosybrown;
  background: #ffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"> item1 </div>
  <div class="item"> item2 </div>
  <div class="item"> item3 </div>
  <div class="item"> item4 </div>
  <div class="item"> item5 </div>
</div>
```

---

### Explanation

***Line-Based Placement***

Let's start by keeping in mind that `grid-row` and `grid-column` are shorthand properties for:

- `grid-row-start` / `grid-row-end`
- `grid-column-start` / `grid-column-end`

[image]

Item #1 is set to span across the first two columns.

```css
.item:nth-child(1) {
   grid-column: 1/3;
 }
```

But it has no rows defined. Therefore, `grid-row` defaults to `auto`.

Item #2 is set to span the first two rows.

```css
.item:nth-child(2) {
   grid-row: 1/3;
}
```

But it has no columns defined. Therefore, `grid-column` defaults to `auto`.

Side note: Because the explicit grid has only one row defined (`grid-template-rows: auto`), and no height defined, Item #2 is actually spanning across two rows—one explicit, one implicit—not just one as it appears. (This matter is worthy of another question.)

[image]

***The Grid Item Placement Algorithm***

The grid item layout process is handled by the [Grid Item Placement Algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-placement-algo). One of the first steps in the process is this:

> 1. Position anything that's not auto-positioned.

Therefore:

- Item #1 gets its defined columns (rows are `auto`).
- Item #2 gets its defined rows (columns are `auto`).

This is how Item #2 gets placed above Item #1. Defined rows and columns have precedence over undefined rows and columns—the latter subject to more control by the algorithm.

As mentioned at the top, the simplest solution is to remove the `auto` variable from the process. You can do this by adding `grid-row: 1` to the first item, or `grid-column: 3` to the second item.

---

### `span`

`grid-row: 1 / 3` is shorthand for:

- `grid-row-start: 1`
- `grid-row-end: 3`

`grid-row: span 2` is equivalent to `grid-row: span 2 / auto`, which is shorthand for:

- `grid-row-start: span 2`
- `grid-row-end: auto`

When you switch from `grid-row: 1 / 3` to `grid-row: span 2`, you remove the `grid-row-start: 1` component. In other words, you unlock the item from the first row. The algorithm now has more control, moving the item to its natural position.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of `grid-template-areas` & `grid-area`, like so:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: rosybrown;
  background: #ffff;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
      "item1 item1 item2"
      "item3 item4 item2"
      "item5 item5 item5"
}

.item {
  background: steelblue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: skyblue 1px solid;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: item1;
  background-color: springgreen;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: royalblue;
  grid-area: item2;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  background: darkred;
  grid-area: item3;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: item4;
}

.item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: item5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"> item1 </div>
  <div class="item"> item2 </div>
  <div class="item"> item3 </div>
  <div class="item"> item4 </div>
  <div class="item"> item5 </div>
</div>
```